# Multiple values for a particular key - JSON

Tags: python, json, shell, jq

JSON Format:

```
{
  "Descriptions": [
    {
      "Name": "Doctor",
      "AttributeDescriptions": [],
      "TypeName": "Professional"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Pilot",
      "AttributeDescriptions": [
        {
          "AttributeValue": "",
          "AttributeName": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Above JSON value is assigned to a variable `DescribeProfession` in a shell script.

My intention is to list all the values of "Name" key. 
When I use the below python code, it only prints first value . ie., Doctor. But I need all the three values,

```
Doctor
Teacher
Pilot
```

```
python -c "import json; DescribeProfession=json.loads('$(echo $DescribeProfession)'); print(DescribeProfession['Descriptions'][0]['Name'])
```

I'm really new to Python scripting.Could you please help me to correct this python script to print all the values of key "Name" from JSON.

Comment: `print(profession['Name'] for profession in DescribeProfession['Descriptions'])`

Comment: Hello @Tomalak,that is the given JSON format to me. I will try to correct it.

Comment: Yep, that's better now!

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? It looks like you just need a loop, right?

Answer (score 2):

Ditch python and use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) instead.

```
jq -rn --argjson in "$DescribeProfession" '$in.Descriptions[].Name'
```

or,

```
jq -r '.Descriptions[].Name' <<<$DescribeProfession
```

or with other alternative ways of feeding a string to a program's stdin.

Comment: Hello @oguz, Thank you for the answer. could you please provide a python related solution. I could not install jq in my linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to loop over all the elements of the `"Descriptions"` value. Second, you should pass the JSON as an argument, not interpolate it into the Python script.

```
python -c 'import json,sys; print("\n".join(x["Name"] for x in json.loads(sys.argv[1])["Descriptions"]))' "$DescribeProfession"
```

Python is not a great choice for writing shell one-liners, though it's much simpler if you embed newlines into the argument.

```
python -c '
import json, sys
d = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
for x in d["Descriptions"]:
  print(x["Name"])
' "$DescribeProfession"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the Name property `DescribeProfession['Descriptions'][0]['Name']` which means the first element from `'Descriptions'` array.

You should loop through the array and print all `DescribeProfession['Descriptions'][i]['Name']`